# How can I make a google map ground overlay that points along the direction of road

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I create an overlay image of an arrow that points to the driving direction as such.

[image]

The road directions vary significantly, the angle, curve is different from time to time, so the arrow has to be flexible enough to adapt to road condition. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not long ago Google added the `Flat Marker` option to the `Google Maps API V2`, take a look here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#flatten_a_marker

You can create it like so:

```
static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.90, 115.86);
Marker perth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(PERTH)
                          .flat(true)
                          .rotation(90.0));
```

and get the rotation parameter by using the bearing sensor of the phone:

Comment: Thanks, This is probably what I am looking for. will try it out. but How can I Bend the arrow if there's turn in the road as compared to a straightforward bearing